# How to prevent Ctrl + c from killing my node process?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use this function for delaying the process from ending right when I am pressing Ctrl + c, but the process stops right away without doing anything.

```
(() => {
    ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM', 'SIGQUIT']
        .forEach(signal => process.on(signal, async () => {
            let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
                setTimeout(() => res("Now it's done!"), 3000)
            });

            // wait until the promise returns us a value
            let result = await promise; 

            // "Now it's done!"
            console.log("=======================YESSSSSSSSSS=======================")

    }));
})();
```

Comment: It shouldn't do anything the way it is setup. The process won't remain open if you don't run something on it. To make this easier, what is your goal? Just to note that if you are just trying to run a node process in the background you can use "node myscript.js &", or as a service use pm2 or something similar. There again if there is nothing running the process will terminate (pm2 is useful for running a node server)

Comment: @Caharpuka thanks for your response. But the promise shouldn't be resolved first before closing the process?

Comment: You run the process, it receives no signal, does not create any promise, and ends. There is nothing here to make it wait till it receives a signal. If you want that you would need some timeout keeping it alive indefinitely till the signal is received.

Comment: Can you show me please how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
const wait = () => setTimeout(wait, 1000); // Loop to keep the process alive

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
                /* Code to run before exiting */
                process.exit()
        }, 3000);
});

wait();
```

However, this doesn't actually check that everything is finished. Ending a process gracefully if you have some I/O operations happening doesn't involve setting a rough grace period for them to finish, but rather letting them report back somehow when they have finished, using Promise.all() or whatever.